# What happens to memory when stack is popped?

Tags: java, c, jvm

I have a function

```
public void f() {
    int x = 72;
    return;
}
```

So `x` is stored at possibly the address `0x9FFF`.

When the function returns, what happens to the **memory** at that address? Is it still there? I.e is the value still `72`? Or is it completely invalidated?

Comment: Why the `C`-tag? Also `return;` is unnecessary.

Comment: In C, for most architectures, the value is still there until another agent overwrite it (i.e. an ISR). In Java, the VM can implement the stack in many different ways and the JIT doesn't translate the VM stack into the native stack necessarily. So, from a Java perspective, it is lost.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Good info, that could actually be added as an answer, it's better than my answer :)

Comment: Superb question by the way, wish I could upvote it more than once

Comment: Note that you can't actually rely on `x` being saved to *any* memory location, seeing as you don't even use it. A typical C compiler or Java JITter will optimize the `int x = 72;` away completely.

Comment: Thanks @EJoshuaS, but this question is too broad. One would begin by noticing that C doesn't mention a stack at all, only an automatic storage that an implementation can implement in any way, while the JLS specifies how the VM stack must work and how bytecode operates on it. Then continue by picking a handful of architectures and showing that most C compilers use the native stack for automatic storage of local vars. One must then show how those stacks are used and work on those architectures, including how deallocation is done and what part of the stack is ephemeral. ...

Comment: ... Then one move on to Java to show how the bytecode, a stack based instruction set, is translated into native code by the JIT, showing in most cases that the JIT translates execution flows and not methods thereby making the question exactly like asking what happen to the `a[0]` after `a.shift()` in JS. Thus marking the Java case as non-recoverable either by Java code or JNI code as the Frames are probably allocated not on the native stack. ...

Comment: ... Finally, one must consider the modern compilers and calling conventions where variables and constants are unfolded and other optimisations applied to the point the most local vars are never created on the stack or created at all. So this question cannot be answered reasonably and will probably attract a lot of LQ answers.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Java programming language and the Java virtual machine do not define what happens to the memory of a stack frame after the frame is popped. This is a low-level implementation detail that is masked by the higher level abstractions. In fact, the Java language and JVM bytecode make it impossible by design to retrieve already-deleted values from the stack (unlike C/C++).

In practice however, stack frames in Java will behave like stack frames in C. Growing the stack will bump its pointer (usually downward) and allocate space to store variables. Shrinking the stack will usually bump the pointer up and simply leave the old values in memory to rot without overwriting them. If you have low-level access to the JVM's stack memory region, this is the behavior you should expect to see.

Note that it is impossible in Java to do a trick like C where you attempt to read uninitialized stack variables:

```
static boolean firstTime = true;

public void f() {
    int x;
    if (firstTime) {
        x = 72;
        firstTime = false;
    } else {
        // Compile error: Variable 'x' may not have been initialized
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Other stack behaviors are possible in JVM implementations. For example, as frames are popped it is possible to unmap the 4 KiB virtual memory pages back to the operating system, which will actually erase the old values. Also on machine architectures such as the [Mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_architecture), stack memory is treated specially so that growing the stack will always return a region filled with zero bytes, which saves the work of actually loading old values from memory.

Answer (score 2):

In C it is *undefined behaviour*.

In practice, if you were to try something like:

```
 int *ptr;

 void foo() {
    bar();
    printf("%d", *ptr);
 }

 void bar() {
     int x = 72;
     ptr = &x;
 }
```

Then it's *likely* that in most implementations of C, `foo()` would print `72`. This is because although the address referenced by `ptr` is available for reallocation, it's not likely to have been re-allocated yet, and nothing has overwritten that memory. The longer your program continues to run, initialising more local variables, and calling `malloc()`, the more likely it is that this memory address will be re-used, and the value will change.

However there's nothing in the C specification that says this must be the case - an implementation *could* zero that address as soon as it goes out of scope, or make the runtime panic when you try to read it, or, well, anything -- that's what "undefined" means.

As a programmer you should take care to avoid doing this. A lot of the time the bugs it would cause would be glaring, but some of the time you'll cause intermittent bugs, which are they hardest kind to track down.

In Java, while it's possible that the memory still contains `72` after it goes out of scope, there is literally no way to access it, so it does not affect the programmer. The only way it could be accessed in Java would be if there were an "official" reference to it, in which case it would not be marked for garbage collection, and isn't really out of scope.

Comment: Good answer overall. But when you say "In Java ... if there were an official reference to it", this is impossible because primitive `int`s are not references.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types in **Java** are placed on the stack (into a *local variables* array of a [frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)). A new frame is created each time a method is invoked:

```
public void foo() {
    int x = 72; // 'x' will be stored in the array of local variables of the frame
}
```

A frame is destroyed when its method invocation completes. At this moment all *local variables* and *partial results* might still reside on the stack, but they are abandoned and no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not looking at the spec offhand, but I'm guessing that this isn't technically defined.

I actually tried something like that in C++ once and it was, in fact, `72` (or whatever I put there before the function call returned) if I remember correctly, so the machine didn't actually go through and write `0` to that location or something.

Some of this is an implementation detail, too. I implemented it in MIPS assembly language as well (I'll include a code sample if I can dig it up). Basically, when I needed registers, I'd just "grow" the stack by however many local variables I needed, store whatever the current values in the registers I needed were (so I could restore them later), and re-use the register. If that's the implementation, then the value could actually contain the value of a local variable *in the caller*. I don't think that that's exactly what Java's doing, though.

**TL;DR** It's an implementation detail, but in C at least odds are it won't overwrite the value in memory until it actually needs it. Java is much harder to predict.